Monthly salary changing from too much to too little, with no response when I highlight this to HR
Background: I'm a junior contacted through a vendor for the org that I work at. I work the same hours each week with no fluctuation on my timesheets. As I'm on a "new talent" scheme, my salary increases every 6 months throughout the scheme.
The problem: For the past 6 months, My salary has varied widely, from being paid too much one month to too much the next, which doesn't work out from an accounting perspective (surely?). To put this in perspective, let's say my monthly salary is meant to be $100, this is how much I've been paid each month:

Month 1: 120
Month 2: 97
Month 3: 90
Month 4: 90
Month 5: 158

I have 1 month left of this work scheme, and somehow I doubt that I will be paid what I'm meant to be paid for the final month. I have written in numerous emails to my line manager and the contracting company's HR, and have received no response. I have saved this additional cash, should it arise that the contracting company requests a refund, but I have not received any sort of response.
Is there anything that I am required to do at this stage?

Might this be a taxation issue? You mentioned being contacted [sic] through a vendor, implied starting in the middle of a tax year, and tagged the UK. Your take home pay will depend on factors like which tax band you are in, how you are contracting (LTD or sole-trading), your earnings prior to starting this role, and how quickly HMRC is dealing with paperworks related to your account.

Q1: is this net pay or gross pay? Q2: Do you get a pay stub or other information with the payment and what does it say? Q3: did you try calling instead of email?

Have they responded to emails on other topics? If they’re straight up ignoring you, I would quit as soon as possible. This sounds not only unprofessional but disrespectful—not the sort of people you want to be depending on for your bread and butter.

By my math and given the example above you should be paid 45.  Anything less than that, I would see a lawyer.  Anything more move on and find a different employer.
Countless times we have heard users of this site tell the same old tale:  "I've sent countless emails or phone calls to no avail".  That is a clear indication they do not care and have no intention of fixing the issue.

If countless emails and phone calls don't do the job, make an appointment to walk into the office and ask. Some people just need personal contact or things get put off for later.

In the UK, look up the official company address on the companieshouse.gov.uk website and write a letter. Any letter to this address is legally received. Even if the company is not at the address, or refuses to accept it. Or throws it in the bin.
